# Onsen-UI ons-carousel not showing images from ajax

Tags: html, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm using ons-carousel to show some images fetched from network using ajax. But the problem is, It's not showing images. but the images and carousel-items are present in the html when I see it in chrome developer tools. 
And I can see the ons-carousel-item visibility is hidden in css. When I make a static ons-carousel which is not loading images from ajax but in the same manner using ng-repeat, the carousel is working fine. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<ons-page controller="hotelDetails">
  <div ng-init="getHotel()">
    <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen var="carousel" noslidingmenu>
                          <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: gray;" ng-repeat="thumb in images" style="visibility: visible">

                            <img src="{{thumb}}" style="width: 100%"/>
                          </ons-carousel-item>

                          <ons-carousel-cover><div class="cover-label">Swipe left or right</div></ons-carousel-cover>
                        </ons-carousel>
    </div>
</ons-page>
```

**AngularJS**

```
module.controller('hotelDetails', function($scope){
var page = $scope.ons.navigator.getCurrentPage();
$scope.id = page.options.id;
$scope.title = page.options.title;

$scope.getHotel = function(){
    console.log('Loading data');
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://domain.com/api/hotels/hoteldetails",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            id: $scope.id
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('Success');
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.images = data.images;
            });
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

});

here is a screenshot of running app.

[image]

Comment: Try adding the `auto-refresh` attribute to the `<ons-carousel>`. It will refresh the carousel every time an item is added.

Comment: <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen auto-refresh var="carousel" noslidingmenu>
           <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: gray;" ng-repeat="img in details.images" style="visibility: visible">
            
             <img src="{{img.thumb}}" style="width: 100%"/>
           </ons-carousel-item>
           
           <ons-carousel-cover><div class="cover-label">Swipe left or right</div></ons-carousel-cover>
         </ons-carousel>
Still not working :(

Comment: What version of Onsen UI are you using? auto-refresh was added in 1.2.2

Comment: I started using 2 weeks ago.. I think 1.2.2 was released after that. If I am right :P

Comment: Mine is 1.2.1. How do I upgrade?

Comment: Ok I have replaced onsen folder inside www. Now $scope.ons.navigator.getCurrentPage(); is not working.

Comment: $scope.myNavigator.getCurrentPage(); works fine..
Use the navigator name except global $scope.ons.navigator.getCurrentPage();.

Comment: @dnx that global variable has been removed from 1.2.2. So yes, use the other way instead :)